# How can I add an attribute to related products?

Tags: magento2.2.6, related-products

I would like to Add the `sku` to the **related products**. I am in the template `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`. This is what it looks like now-

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */
?>

<?php
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

case 'related-rule':
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Accessories');
        $items = $block->getAllItems();
        $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
        $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
break;

case 'related':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
    if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Related Products');
        $items = $block->getItems();
        $limit = 0;
        $shuffle = 0;
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
break;

case 'upsell-rule':
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'upsell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'upsell_products_list';
        $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
        $items = $block->getAllItems();
        $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
        $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();

        $showAddTo = false;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
break;

case 'upsell':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
    if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
        $type = 'upsell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'upsell_products_list';
        $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
        $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
        $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
        $shuffle = 0;

        $showAddTo = false;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
break;

case 'crosssell-rule':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'crosssell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
        $title = __('More Choices:');
        $items = $block->getItemCollection();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
break;

case 'crosssell':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
    if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
        $type = 'crosssell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
        $title = __('More Choices:');
        $items = $block->getItems();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
break;

case 'new':
    if ($exist = $block->getProductCollection()) {
        $type = 'new';
        $mode = 'grid';
        $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

        $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

        $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
        $title = __('New Products');
        $items = $exist;

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
break;

default:
    $exist = null;
}
?>

<?php if ($exist):?>

<?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
    <?php if ($type == 'related'): ?>
        <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>" data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}' data-limit="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $limit ?>" data-shuffle="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $shuffle ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="block-title title">
    <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading">
    <?php if ($type == 'related' && $canItemsAddToCart): ?>
    <div class="block-actions">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Check items to add to the cart or') ?>
        <button type="button" class="action select" role="select-all"><span id="selectall"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('select all') ?></span></button>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
            <?php $available = ''; ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                    <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">' ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                    <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                </a>
                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                    <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                    </strong>

                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                        <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                            <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                <div class="field choice related">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                    <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                    <div class="actions-primary">
                                        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                ?>
                                                <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                        data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                        type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                    <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                        <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                            <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= ($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like this to be inbetween the name and price so I add this line-

```
 <div><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?></div>
```

It doesn't work. How can I add sku to my related products?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?> is correct I had a cache issue. I will leave this up for anyone else needing to add an attribute to related products.
```